# No Apps Can Perform This Action - Opening Image

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-mediaplayer

I'm attempting to view an image after selecting it using Gallery launched via intent however I'm getting an error when attempting to do so. I think this may have to do with:

```
intent.setDataAndType(selectedVideo, "video/*, image/*");
```

or some sort of conflict in onActivityResult between opening images and video - but I'm not sure.

Any input is greatly appreciated:

P.S.

Ideally this would open the image using the gallery once it is selected - not open it using my app.

### Source:

```
ImageButton pb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photos);
        pb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
//              Toast.makeText(UI.this, "Before and After Photos",
//                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            }
        });

        ImageButton vb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.video);
        vb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
//              Toast.makeText(UI.this, "Video Testimonial", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
//                      .show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("video/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_VIDEO);

            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedVideo = data.getData();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(selectedVideo, "video/*, image/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Complete action using"));  



            }

        }

        ;


    }
}
```

### Edit:

I'm trying to accomplish a very simple task:

I need to be able to click the imageButton for video, select from gallery and play, and click the imageButton for images, select an image and view it - ALL USING THE GALLERY

How might this be accomplished?

### Current Source:

```
        ImageButton pb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photos);
        pb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            }
        });

        ImageButton vb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.video);
        vb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
    .show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("video/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_VIDEO);

            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedVideo = data.getData();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(selectedVideo, "video/*, image/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Complete action using"));  



            }

        }

        ;


    }
}
```

Comment: to view a image you need to first open the gallery select the image get the uri and set the image selected to imageview. I don't see where you set the image to imageview

Comment: I basically copied what I was using for Video - how should I change it in order for it to function?

Comment: @user3507894 you haven't understood. You copy pasted the code that i posted on your previous post. That is your problem

Answer (score 0):

What you have

```
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

Then you have

```
if (requestCode == 1) {
```

Then

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(selectedVideo, "video/*, image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                    "Complete action using"));
```

You are trying to use intent chooser and android says there is no app that can perform the action.

You need to change to

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
             iv.setImageURI(selectedImage);

        }

    }
```

Example:

I have used a ImageView to display the image selected from gallery

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


        private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 100;

        ImageView iv;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                ImageButton ab = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
                ab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Testimonial", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                .show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                                Intent.ACTION_PICK
                                                );
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                startActivityForResult(intent,  SELECT_PHOTO);
                        }
                });


        }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (requestCode ==  SELECT_PHOTO) {
                        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                                iv.setImageURI(selectedImage);

                        }

                }
        }
}
```

To the edited question

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;
    private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 101;
    private static final int SELECT_VIDEO = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fg);

            ImageButton ab = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            ab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Audio Testimonial", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(
                                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                    }
            });

            ImageButton vb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
            vb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Video Testimonial", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                            photoPickerIntent.setType("video/*");
                            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_VIDEO);

                    }

            });
    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO) {
                     {
                            Uri selectedVideo = data.getData();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setDataAndType(selectedVideo, "video/*");
                            startActivity(intent);

                    }
            }
            else if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO) {

                          Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                          Intent intent = new Intent();
                          intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                          intent.setDataAndType(selectedImage,"image/*");
                          startActivity(intent);
              }

            }



//            ImageButton wb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
//            wb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//                    public void onClick(View v) {
//                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Written Testimonial",
//                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Written.class);
//                            startActivity(intent);
//                    }
//            });

            ImageButton pb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
            pb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Before and After Photos",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
                    }
            });
      }
    }
```

Comment: This results in the image being diplayed within my app - I'd like it  displayed using the gallery app - is that possible?\

Comment: @user3507894 yes. If not what is that you want??

Comment: @user3507894  User can open the gallery itself and view the image there itself. Why open gallery from your app then??

Comment: I want to open the image, fullscreen using the gallery app - not within my app (which is what the code above is doing)

Comment: It is by design - when the user clicks the image within my app I need to to load full screen - either within my app - or the gallery (either one will work - but adding the imageview as a tiny icon above my existing buttons as the code above seems to do - is not an option)

Comment: I would prefer to launch the gallery - which will display the image full screen by default (launching the video imagebutton causes the gallery to open - I would like the same for images)

Comment: Also - your current answer breaks the video section of the app - I need to be able to open video and images once they are clicked so I need an appropreate solution for my onActivityResult

Comment: @user3507894 first of all there is no mention of the video in your code. secondly you haven't understood my previous post and this. Thirdly you edited your question now. Fourthly no one is going to code for you.

Comment: There IS mention of video in the code... LOOK at it!! 2. Yes I DID understand your previous post (and I got it to work) 3. I'm not asking anyone to - I'm asking for an onActivityResult that will open both images and video - which shouldnt be too hard

Comment: Your most recent solution changes the onActivityResult and causes the images to open, and also sets an imageView within the app - which is not what is needed

Comment: @user3507894 that is only after editing your question by the time i had already answered.

Comment: I simply need to be able to click the imageButton for video, select from gallery and play, and click the imageButton for images, select an image and view it - ALL USING THE GALLERY

Comment: @user3507894 posted an edit. Next time ask a question properly.

Comment: I updated my post (I apologize) if there is anything else I can do to assist please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In Huawei P9, android marshmallow, one device has not any application that can manage that intent's request (it has no gallery nor photo app). So manually installed those app and worked perfectlly